# Arrows in RBokeh

Tags: arrows, rbokeh

Working with the rbokeh package I have created a figure p, where I'd like to add some arrows.
I'm able to add lines with the ly_segments command, but I can't seem to find a command to add arrows?
Do I miss something, or does this function not exist in the RBokeh package?